# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select word occurrences in just one line in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, multicursorediting

I know the topic of multi cursors-editing in visual studio code is duplicate but what I want is the way (by keyboard) to select word occurrences in **just one line** in visual studio code, because the other option: ctrl + F2 it selects all the occurrences in all the file, and not the mouse way by holding alt and click.

let say I have this:

```
const FETCH_USERS_REQUEST = "FETCH_USERS_REQUEST"; 
const FETCH_USERS_REQUEST = "FETCH_USERS_REQUEST";
```

when the cursor is on REQUEST word for the second line I want to do two cursors in the second line after the two occurrences of REQUEST.

Comment: you can select the first occurrence of the text you want, and then with Ctrl+D add more occurrences, if you do to many use Ctrl+U

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 alternatives:

1. Enable the `Find in Selection` option in the Find Widget **after** entering your find query.
2. An extension that I wrote does this fairly well, see [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).

With this simple keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",             // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "restrictFind": "line"   // find all on current line only
      // with multiple cursors you can have as many current lines as you wish
  }
}
```

It does a find in the current file.  Since there is no actual find query, like `REQUEST`, designated in the `args`.  It will find the current word at the cursor on the line.  Different languages define what a "word" is differently.  For javascript, for example, `FETCH_USERS_REQUEST` is the current word even if the cursor is on `Request` only.

You can manage this by actually selecting, double-clicking on `Request` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and then trigger the above keybinding.  Then the extesnion will search for whatever is selected, if there is a non-empty selection.

The extension is designed to select those find matches, not put the cursor after them, but you can simply right-arrow to dismiss the selection and the cursor will be where you want.

[I have to update the extension, the current version v0.9.7 in the Marketplace won't do this - but here is a demo of it already working.  It should be updated tomorrow at the latest, look for v0.9.8.]

[image: find word on line]